# Leave unknown x on left part

Tags: linear-algebra

I need formula for calculating $x$, but I do not know how to simplify this function (leave $x$ on left part, everything else on right):

$60x - 5(1.3^x) = 3$

Comment: There is no formula to solve this equation (except possibly using Lambert's function). You have to use numerical methods.

Comment: ? solve(x=1,30,60*x-5*1.3^x-3)
%54 = 21.08101457181377919434706967
? solve(x=0,1,60*x-5*1.3^x-3)
%55 = 0.1363688379660755610385740893
are the solutions which I calculated with PARI. Since the second derivate of $60x-5*1.3^x-3$ is always negative, there are no more solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There si no solution to this equation in terms of elementary functions. However, the solution exists in terms of Lambert function. Writing the equation in a more general form $$a x+b c^x+d=0$$ the solution is given by 
$$x=-\frac{W\left(\frac{b \log (c) c^{-\frac{d}{a}}}{a}\right)}{\log (c)}-\frac{d}{a}$$ Using your numbers $a=60,b=-5,c=1.3,d=-3$, we the find a solution close to $0.136369$.

More generally, any equation which can be written as $$a +b x+c \log(d+e x)=0$$ has a solution in terms of Lambert function.

If you do not access Lambert function, then the only solution would be numerical. Let us try Newton, which starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}$$ In your case, let us start at $x=0$; then Newton scheme generates the following iterates :$0.136314$, $0.136369$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

**Added later**

Very correctly, Peter pointed out that, in this approach, one root is missing. Plotting the function, there is, as Peter told, a second root close to $x=21$. So let us repeat Newton scheme with $x_0=21$. The iterates are $21.0821$, $21.0810$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: Nice answer, but with both methods, the second solution is not found. This is however no problem, simply search the sign changes (here 0-1 and 21-22) of f(x), then use some numerical method to calculate the positions of the roots.

Comment: @Peter. You are totally correct. I shall edit my answer an quote you. Cheers :)